# navigating to a target of different page in cshtml (razor) with MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, hyperlink

I have a link in home page (contact us), that need to be redirected to particular section of HTML in a different page. In plain HTML, <`a href="/all.html#contact">contact</a>` I know it works. But when using with MVC4, if I use `<a href="/Home/all#contact">contact</a>` its not navigating to the section of a page. Is there anything I am missing?

I have a `<div id="contact" ...` in the target page.

Comment: What you have is correct `<a href="/controller/action#target">contact</a>`. What browser are you using? This seems to be broken on my Chrome but works in FF.

Comment: --This seems to be broken on my Chrome but works in FF.-- *Working for me now*